# iOS app removed from store, deleted from itunes connect, but still available on TestFlight

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I deleted my iOS App from AppStore and from iTunes Connect too, but if I upload a new build from XCode's Organizer, it will update the app on TestFlight. How is that possible? I can't manage the test flight build because it isn't on iTunes Connect anymore.(can't add users for example). How do I delete the app from TestFlight?

Answer (score 0):

You can expire your build in Test flight.
[image]